# Как скомпилировать приложение для ios в android studio?

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

Подскажите как в android studio скомпилировать приложение для ios написанное на flutter

Пример простого webview приложения

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
}

class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Судя по беглому гуглению - никак. Для билда iOS приложения вам нужен Mac и XCode.

Comment: я конечно не эксперт и могу ошибаться, но по-моему название android studio говорит само за себя

Comment: Про android studio я знаю я просто не разу не делал приложения для ios и как там сделать приложение конкретно под ios не знаю

Comment: iOS можно собирать только на MacOS (с любовью от Apple)

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас mac, то пройтись по шагам в соответствующем разделе [документации](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios).

Кратко:

---

Если хотите просто запустить на iPhone: подключаете устройство, открываете Xcode, регистрируете устройство, в терминале / консоли Android Studio:

```
flutter run
```

и выбрать нужное устройство:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для выгрузки в AppStore / экспорта AdHoc сборки и прочего в терминале / консоли Android Studio:

```
flutter build ios --release
```

Открываем Xcode и проходим стандартную процедуру сборки и выгрузки / экспорта.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то в android studio тоже можно собрать файл для выгрузки в app store?